# READ 433mhz DEVICES

Tags: arduino-uno, rf

I have an issue with **433mhz reading**. I have two cheap transmitter and receiver boards, the most known ones : [image: Devices]

I followed several tutorials, and **I'm using the [rc switch](https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch) library.**

I'm trying to read the signal sent by a remote control, (stores), as I would like to duplicate it, to control the store. I firstly tried with the basic code to read 433mhz signals, but it didn't work. **Assuming that there is an encryption between the two devices**, *(I'm not sure if that this is the case, but internet didn't help to find if it's usually the cases for those devices, and how to tell if mine has encryption, **It would be nice if I can get some help on that too**)*, I decided to upload a code to get raw data, sent by any transmissions.

The problem is that there is absolutely **no data coming out from the receptor when I use the rc switch library**. I have another Arduino constantly sending float values with a transmitter, and **it works if I use virtualwires**, but it doesn't show anything on the serial monitor with rc switch. I also tried with my store remote control, and a garage remote control, but nothing is showing up.

Here is the code of the receiver :

```
/*
  Example for analyzing and proposing unknown new protocols

  https://github.com/Martin-Laclaustra/rc-switch/

  Requires modified rc-switch branch "protocollessreceiver"
  with ReceivedInverted() function exposed.
*/

#include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySwitch.enableReceive(0);  // Receiver on interrupt 0 => that is pin #2
  // Use mySwitch.enableReceive(D2); for ESP8266
  Serial.println("beginned");
}

void loop() {
  if (mySwitch.available()) {

    int value = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();

    if (value == 0) {
      Serial.print("Unknown encoding");
    } else {

      int databuffer[64]; // get a copy of the received timings before they are overwritten
      int numberoftimings = 2 * mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength() + 2;
      if (numberoftimings > 64) numberoftimings = 64;
      for (int i = 0; i < numberoftimings; i++) {
        databuffer[i] = mySwitch.getReceivedRawdata()[i];
      }

      Serial.print("Received ");
      Serial.print( mySwitch.getReceivedValue() );
      Serial.print(" / ");
      Serial.print( mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength() );
      Serial.print("bit ");
      Serial.print("Protocol: ");
      Serial.println( mySwitch.getReceivedProtocol() );

      unsigned int databitsoffset = abs( (int)mySwitch.getReceivedLevelInFirstTiming() - (int)mySwitch.getReceivedInverted());
      //Serial.println( mySwitch.getReceivedLevelInFirstTiming() );
      //Serial.println( mySwitch.getReceivedInverted() );
      //Serial.println( databitsoffset );
      unsigned long dataduration = 0;
      for (unsigned int i = 1 + databitsoffset; i < numberoftimings - 1 + databitsoffset; i++) {
        dataduration += databuffer[i];
      }
      Serial.print("data bits of pulse train duration: ");
      Serial.println( dataduration );
      unsigned int averagebitduration = (int)(0.5 + ((double)dataduration) / mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength());
      unsigned int protocolratio = (unsigned int)(0.5 + ((double)(averagebitduration - mySwitch.getReceivedDelay())) / (double)mySwitch.getReceivedDelay());
      Serial.print("proposed protocol: { ");
      Serial.print(mySwitch.getReceivedDelay());
      Serial.print(", { ");
      Serial.print( (databitsoffset == 0) ?
                    (int) (0.5 + (double)databuffer[2 * mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength() + 1] / (double)mySwitch.getReceivedDelay())
                    :
                    (int) (0.5 + (double)databuffer[0] / (double)mySwitch.getReceivedDelay())
                  );
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print( (databitsoffset == 0) ?
                    (int) (0.5 + (double)databuffer[0] / (double)mySwitch.getReceivedDelay())
                    :
                    (int) (0.5 + (double)databuffer[1] / (double)mySwitch.getReceivedDelay())
                  );
      Serial.print(" }, { ");
      Serial.print("1");
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(protocolratio);
      Serial.print(" }, { ");
      Serial.print(protocolratio);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print("1");
      Serial.print(" }, ");
      Serial.print((mySwitch.getReceivedInverted()) ? "true" : "false" );
      Serial.println(" }");

      // raw signal
      Serial.println("====");
      Serial.print("first level ");
      Serial.println((mySwitch.getReceivedLevelInFirstTiming() == 0) ? "down" : "up" );
      for (int i = 0; i < 2 * mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength() + 2 - 1 + databitsoffset; i++) {
        Serial.print(databuffer[i]);
        Serial.print(" ");
        if ((i - databitsoffset) % 16 == 0) Serial.println("");
      }
      if ((2 * mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength() + 2 - 1 + databitsoffset - 1) % 16 != 0) Serial.println("");
      if (databitsoffset != 1) Serial.println(databuffer[2 * mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength() + 1]);
      // plot signal in spreadsheet
      Serial.println("====");

    }

    mySwitch.resetAvailable();
  }
}
```

*I am aware that interruptPin(0) = pin #2 on Arduino*

Here is the layout :

[image: Layout]

**Does anyone have an idea of why I can't get anything on my serial monitor ?, I'll take any help !**

Comment: there is no encryption ... it's just a wireless wire ... connect a switch to the transmitter and an LED to the receiver ... otherwise, connect a GPIO output to the transmitter and a GPIO input to the receiver

Comment: For stores i don't think there is, but I read that garage door have that system, but don't know how to check. For the setup this is exactly what i have done : Data is going out from a GPIO to the transmitter, and reversed for the receiver. What's wrong ?

Comment: try to read with SimpleScanner, you can find sketch here:
https://github.com/sui77/SimpleRcScanner/blob/master/htdocs/Sketchbook/SimpleRcScanner.ino